# How insert a value with semicolon in field with jdbc?

Tags: sql, spring, jdbc, h2

I have :

```
`<beans profile="h2">
        <import resource="classpath:config/db-config.xml" />
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config/batch.h2.properties" />
        <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
          <jdbc:script location="classpath:rendicontazione/configurazione/create_configurazione.sql"/>
          <jdbc:script location="classpath:rendicontazione/configurazione/insert_configurazione.sql"/>
        </jdbc:initialize-database>
        <import resource="classpath:config/batch-context-test.xml" />
    </beans>`
```

the error lies inside insert_configurazione.sql.

QUERY :

```
INSERT INTO CONFIGURAZIONE (DOMINIO,CHIAVE,VALORE) 
     VALUES ('XXX','YYY','a;b;c;d;e;f');
```

If I try with:

```
INSERT INTO CONFIGURAZIONE (DOMINIO,CHIAVE,VALORE) 
     VALUES ('XXX','YYY','"a;b;c;d;e;f"');
```

The row is inserted but the value of `VALORE` is `"a;b;c;d;e;f"`.

OR

`INSERT INTO CONFIGURAZIONE (DOMINIO,CHIAVE,VALORE) 
         VALUES ('XXX','YYY','a\;b\;c\;d\;e\;f');`
The result is : `a\;b\;c\;d\;e\;f\;`

I want the value of `VALORE` = `a;b;c;d;e;f`

Stacktrace:

```
INSERT INTO CONFIGURAZIONE (DOMINIO,CHIAVE,VALORE) VALUES ('XXX','YYY','a [42000-197]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:203)
at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:548)
at org.h2.command.Parser.checkRunOver(Parser.java:4080)
at org.h2.command.Parser.initialize(Parser.java:3989)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:322)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:311)
at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:278)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:611)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:549)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1247)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:217)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:205)
at com.jolbox.bonecp.StatementHandle.execute(StatementHandle.java:254)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:473)
... 55 more
```

Comment: I have also tried with:
 `INSERT INTO CONFIGURAZIONE (DOMINIO,CHIAVE,VALORE) 
     VALUES ('XXX','YYY','a\;b\;c;d\;e\;f');`

`INSERT INTO CONFIGURAZIONE (DOMINIO,CHIAVE,VALORE) 
     VALUES ('XXX','YYY','a/;b/;c;d/;e/;f');`

Comment: Please use normal case for your title, all capitals are harder to read and it is considered shouting. Also please post a [mcve] and make sure to include the relevant exception stacktrace.

Comment: The posted stacktrace is incomplete. It misses the actual exception.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
INSERT INTO CONFIGURAZIONE (DOMINIO,CHIAVE,VALORE) 
     VALUES ('XXX','YYY','"a\;b\;c\;d\;e\;f"');
```

Comment: This is the result : "a\;b\;c\;d\;e\;f"